# Why do I need CMake for a qMake Project at QtCreator?

Tags: c++, cmake, qt5, qt-creator, visual-studio-2017

I want to compile and link the QtWebEngineWidgets Library and for that I need a MSVC Compiler. Therefor QtCreator(Version 4.2.1) recognized the Visual Studio 2017 Installation on my system but it's not working at all, because the kit shows the Error:

Cmake configuration has no path to a C Compiler set, even though the Kit has a valid tool chain.

The Same error occures for the C++ Compiler at the set. Could you please explain to me, why the Kit needs Cmake for linking and how can I fix this?

Comment: C-make has a prefix-path command that compiles and builds binaries for source files in c++ keeping linked paths, dependancies and resources connected as specified in a text file. Which is why it has to be used. At least in my experience (using it for a class currently). Now why QT depends on CMake I have no idea. So I'll upvote your question since I could learn from the answer as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s a warning and you can use the Kit for non-CMake purposes. (Where is your error?)
Your CMake Configuration at the bottom of the *Kits* tab is probably empty or broken, try *Change* and *Reset*.

QtWebEngine needs CMake because Chromium (as part of it) seems to use it and it is used for tests.

Why do you want to build the library yourself though? It’s part of the official downloads (the VS2015 builds are compatible with VS2017).

Comment: I dont't want to build the Library, I want to link it into a Program. My Error is shown when I hover over the Kit in the Cofiguration. [shown here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B15e0koIIT1CUmhjR2lCZDM0UVU) Maybe the "compile and link" in my question is a bit irritating.

Comment: @Chrystalkey The error is far more interesting, it’s possible that QtCreator is erroneously convinced that you can’t use VS2017 with the VS2015 Qt libraries. Can you still try to load the project and build, what’s the output then?

Comment: [this one](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B15e0koIIT1CZnVUak85RU1DbVk) It really seems to be an error within VS2017. So if I downgrade the error should be fixed... is there a way to get it working with VS2017?

Comment: @Chrystalkey This is just a warning, does it build anything?

Comment: No, it doesn't. There is no compiler output.

Comment: There is no other output at all.

Comment: @Chrystalkey you can try to select the VS2015 toolset which you may have also available as part of your VS2017 installation. Otherwise it may be necessary to tinker the mkspec files of Qt.

Comment: @Chrystalkey you can also try cloning your C and C++ compiler and then, while QtCreator is closed, edit the ABI in `%APPDATA%\Roaming\QtProject\qtcreator\toolchains.xml` from `x86-windows-msvc2017-pe-64bit` to `x86-windows-msvc2015-pe-64bit`

Comment: It worked with the VS2015 Toolset after a reinstallation of VS2017 and QtCreator. Thanks a lot for the help. :D